# how to aggregate by month of datetime in pandas frame?

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate

I have the table below in a Pandas dataframe:

name birth

```
jack 1989-11-17

joe  1988-09-10

ben  1980-10-20

kate 1985-05-15

nichos 1986-07-05

john  1989-11-12

tom   1980-10-25

jason 1985-05-21

eron  1985-07-10

yun   1989-11-05

kung  1986-07-01
```

i want to do some aggregation by the month of birth,the results should be like this :

```
moth cnt

1989-11 3

1988-09 1

1986-07 2

1985-07 1

1985-05 2

1980-10 2
```

Is there any convenience way of doing this?
Many thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make your data into a TimeSeries object and then call resample:

```
s.resample("M", how="count")
```

Comment: Thanks it works, it does want the datetime as an index though, not a column, needed `.set_index()`